# Input field shows model value instead of label after select

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

After selecting an item in the typeahead dropdown, the input field reflects the item's value (now the bound model's value). How would I go about using the label for input value. Is there support here in typeahead directive which I'm not seeing?

My expression:

```
person.id as person.name for person in persons
```

I've also tried using using typeahead-input-formatter, but that only has the $model (value) property available, not the label.

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/OylBlT5KxNvKtTHac61f?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be using typeahead with slightly different intentions. I realized that a better approach would be to bind the typeahead to a garbage(unused) property, and utilize something like `<input ... typeahead-on-select="realBinding = $item.id">`

Comment: Adding to this answer, the expression `person.id as person.name for person in persons` needs to be changed to `person as person.name for person in persons` which means the model we are using with the input field is not the one which contain the required ID. We need to use another variable (`realBinding` as in this answer) to get the ID.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with your plnkr

can you change the syntax for typeahead like below

```
>  <input type="text" ng-model="userId" typeahead="person.name as
> person.name for person in persons | filter : $viewValue" />

typeahead="person.name as person.name for person in persons
```

change person.id to person.name.

it is working, let me know if you still face problem.

Comment: The value I want to assigned to my model should be person.id.

Comment: @Rob, This is how typeahead works,if you give typeahead = "person.id as  person.name for person in persons. when you do search with rob it gives you search based on your names but when you select the item it will return the value to model,because in syntax person.id will return to model. can you let me know what is the reason u need id ?

Answer (score 0):

Change Your expression to 
  **person.name as person.name for person in persons**

If you have to show name in dropdown instead of ID and also after select name , In model you have to show name only.
 then you can use this expression
 **person.name for person in persons**
Here you no need to define persion.id in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

thats not how it works.

You can do this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="start typing..." typeahead-on-select="itemSelected($item, $model, $label)" typeahead="person.name for person in people">
```

Then in your controller, define the on-select function callback:

```
$scope.itemSelected = function(item, model, label){
    $scope.user_id = item.id;
};
```

Basically, when you are passing in objects to the typeahead, you can choose what value to show in the textbox, but not a hidden id as well. Unlike a `select` control, text boxes don't have value and label - only value.